# Created a simple java web framework, don' t find a way to load css, js and other ressources into the jsp pages

Tags: java, web, model-view-controller, servlets, frameworks

I created a simple java web framework with jakarta servlet
Every url is mapped to MainServlet
The web.xml is:

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

In the MainServlet, everything is handled by the function processor

```
public void processor(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception {
        String url = req.getRequestURL().toString();
        String last = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf(getContext())+getContext().length()+1);
        if (getMappingUrls().containsKey(last)){
            // handle normal for controller to view dispatch
        }
        else {
            // check for css,js and other ressources
            String tot = "";
            ServletContext servletContext = req.getServletContext();
            URL resourceUrl = servletContext.getResource(last);
               try {
                    File cssFile = new File(resourceUrl.toURI());
                    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(cssFile);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        tot += line;
                    }

                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
                  
                }
            writer(resp,tot);
        }
```

In my code above, I was able to load a css file as I can see its content in the navigator sources
However the css doesn' t apply to the page unless if I modify it in the browser
Every help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> I was able to load a css file as I can see its content in the navigator sources

I'm not sure I understand what "I can see its content in the navigator sources" means, but if indeed your server correctly delivers the full contents of the CSS file in response to requests for the same, then that's the limit of its responsibility with respect to those files.

> However the css doesn' t apply to the page unless if I modify it in the browser

That suggests that either the page that references the stylesheet does so incorrectly, or else that the CSS, as served, is incorrect.  It is unlikely to be a matter of the bits presented in the question, though those are too incomplete for certainty on that score.